# Esxi virtual machine Debian/Centos crash

Tags: virtualization, vmware-esxi, virtual-machines, vps

my virtual machine ESXI regularly crashes on every linux. I've tried also debian and centos. The same problem. Machine hangs and starting consuming lots of cpu.

I'm running ESXI on Dell T110 with Intel Xeon, SAS HDD and 8GB of RAM.

Here is screenshot from machine state after crash.

Crash image [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT6L8.png)

Comment: version of esxi? versions of debian/centos? version of vmware tools installed on the vm? Are you running open-vm-tools from the repositories or installing the vmware-tools from vmware?

Comment: Esxi 6.5, debian 9.0.0, no vmware-tools. Maybe that's the reason?

Comment: try installing the open-vm-tools, the crash is related to the vmxnet3 driver.

Comment: Vm tools installed. Same problem

Comment: there is a thread in the debian lists about this, but I cannot see a solution: https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/07/threads.html#00173

Comment: Checked again, after vm-tools instalation looks like it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the adapter type from vmxnet3 to E1000e and the problem went away on Debian 9, ESXi 6.5, Dell Poweredge t310.